# How to setHeadIndent for a NSMutableParagraphStyle?

Tags: ios, ipad, coding-style, indentation, paragraph

I am trying to set the Head Indent for a OAMutableParagraphStyle, but It is giving me and error

*TextEditor[7143:40b] Finish porting -[OAMutableParagraphStyle setHeadIndent:] at /Users/shokry/OmniGroup/Frameworks/OmniAppKit/OpenStepExtensions.subproj/OAParagraphStyle.m:387*

this is my peace of code :

OAMutableParagraphStyle *mutatis = [style mutableCopy];
[mutatis setHeadIndent:1.0];
didMutate = YES;
[object setParagraphStyle:mutatis fromInspectorSlice:self];
[mutatis release];

My goal is to do Indentation for the OmniGroup Text Editor available on github.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is they hadn't implemented it yet. They have now though. Seems weird that they didn't just implement those setters originally, since they're 1-line functions.